# Reset colors on Windows command line (cmd)

Tags: windows, colors, command-line

I often run commands in cmd.exe that have pretty colors in their output, which is great.  Unfortunately, sometimes they die in the middle, or I have to kill them, and then the console window itself gets stuck in (say) red text on black background, which is awkward.

How do I reset the text color to the default?

On a unix terminal, I can type [`reset`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/reset) -- I'm looking for the cmd.exe equivalent of that.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

**`Color 07`** will set it to the default scheme that cmd.exe uses.

> Color attributes are specified by TWO
>   hex digits -- the first corresponds to
>   the background; the second the
>   foreground.  Each digit can be any of
>   the following values:

```
0 = Black       8 = Gray
1 = Blue        9 = Light Blue
2 = Green       A = Light Green
3 = Aqua        B = Light Aqua
4 = Red         C = Light Red
5 = Purple      D = Light Purple
6 = Yellow      E = Light Yellow
7 = White       F = Bright White
```

Comment: All 3 answers so far are very helpful, but `color 07` (and not just `color`) worked here, so I'll mark this one.

Comment: `color` has on my environment the same effect as `color 75` (purple on light gray), a combination that I set as the default in console's settings (and that I would like to remove now). `color 07` turns my console into a scary white on red.

Comment: Disappointing that `color 00` doesn't work...

Comment: Can't believe I've been quitting the console for years every time one of my tools went awry, when I could have just done this... :(

Answer (score 38):

Try `Color`

Use `color /?` to see all the commands

> COLOR If no argument is given, this command restores the color to what it was
>   when CMD.EXE started.  This value either comes from the current console
>   window, the /T command line switch or from the DefaultColor registry
>   value.

Comment: +1 for quoting the docs instead of linking to not even official information :-)

Answer (score 13):

Well according to: 
http://commandwindows.com/vista-commands.htm

You just type COLOR.

Worked for me just now...

Comment: Dang, beat me to it.