# Reset colors on Windows command line (cmd) when ssh'd into another box

Tags: cygwin, cmd.exe, colors

This is pretty close to a duplicate of this question:
[Reset colors on Windows command line (cmd)](https://superuser.com/questions/158759/reset-colors-on-windows-command-line-cmd)

The difference is that I'm ssh'd into a unix box with Cygwin...

When I call `reset` I don't get my windows cmd colors back, and when I call `color` the unix box has no idea what I'm talking about...

Is there some way to get my colors back without closing my ssh connection?

Comment: Why do you think that the Unix box could know anything about your local cmd colors ?  Are you using mintty as cygwin terminal ? Which color setup are you looking for ?

Comment: I don't think the unix box could know anything about the local cmd colors... That's why I've posted this question. I'm using cmd.exe. I'd hope for some way to "reset" colors in the menu

Comment: Do you mean local cygwin color (mintty ?) or really cmd.exe ? I was not aware that cmd.exe can handle colors. To change the colors on the unix box, you can change the PS1 settings . https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bash/Prompt_customization

Comment: Really cmd.exe -- it [can handle colors](https://github.com/neilpa/cmd-colors-solarized/blob/master/solarized-dark.reg). It usually does OK until an application changes color schemes (usually Vim) and then doesn't change them back for some reason on exit

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/158759/reset-colors-on-windows-command-line-cmd

Comment: That's the exact same link in my original post

Comment: Then the question should be:  how I can obtain the color scheme that I using on my CMD.exe on a remote connection ? An the only solution I know it to change the PS1 on the remote.